# How to use MS Fakes setter?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, microsoft-fakes

I'm using a Fakes constructor:

```
ShimClassA.Constructor = (@this) =>
{
 var shim = new ShimClass(@this);
};
```

but I also need to set a property in the constructor:

```
ShimClassA.Constructor = (@this) =>
{
 var shim = new ShimClass(@this);
 shim.PropertyB = new FakesDelegate.Action<ClassB>...
};
```

When I type in the keyword *`new`*, intellisense fills in the *`FakesDelegate.Action<ClassB>`* part.  I'm not sure what comes next.  Anyone have some idea on the syntax and what else should go there?  I know it is a delegate but I don't know what it is looking for.

Comment: why do you want to set the property. You can shim the getter of the property to return what ever you want.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using a shim on the inside there? My first inclination would be to use a stub.

Comment: @Magus: ClassA doesn't have an interface so you can't use a stub.

Comment: That's a common misconception, but I'll believe you that the property in question is non-virtual. Yogendra's answer shows the correct way of shimming functionality. Using shims in a non-static way seems incredibly strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shim.PropertyBSet = s=>{};
```

another way of doing is in the constructor

```
ShimClassA.Constructor =(@this)=>
{
   var shim = new Shimclass(@this){PropertyBSet=s=>{};};
}
```

I am not sure, if you would get any benefit out of this. I would still advise to shim the getter of the PropertyB to return whatever you like.

```
ShimClass.AllInstances.PropertyBGet =()=>{return something;};
```